# How do you open a .py file using git bash

Tags: git

I'm trying to open a **.py** file in the current directory on the `gitBash`. Is there any way to open .py file on git bash and edit the .py file inside the gitBash.

Totally new to python

[Picture of the current directory in which .py file resides is shown ]
[image: Picure of GitBash]

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 pro Version 10.0.17134

Comment: Why don't you use an editor instead of a Shell? Git is used for version control.

Comment: @Cristoph I just wanted to know for a very minor change instead of opening a .py file in an editor can we do it on the gitbash to save time ?

Comment: A shell runs commands, it's not an editor. Run an editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vim` embedded in git bash. Try to type `vim {filename}` in bash.

Comment: But please be warned that `vim` is quite a special editor and has a steep learning curve.

Comment: You are right @phd but that's easy way to open file "inside" git bash. Just need to remember **Esc** and `:q!` when something strange happened.

Comment: Also, if you need to do a lot of editing of Python code you'd be better off using a code editor such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or a [Python IDE](https://jaxenter.com/top-5-ides-code-editors-python-146136.html)

Comment: @HeatfanJohn as we can see path is ../PyCharmCE... so it looks like there is an IDE.